# data grouping question but based on a "window"

Tags: python, pyspark, window

All,

I have a dataset which has the definition as follows:

```
eno|date|attendance
1|01-Jan-2010|P
1|02-Jan-2010|P
1|03-Jan-2010|A
1|04-Jan-2010|P
1|05-Jan-2010|P
2|01-Jan-2010|P
2|02-Jan-2010|P
2|03-Jan-2010|P
2|04-Jan-2010|A
2|05-Jan-2010|P
```

For every employee, the requirement is to create an "interval group" which basically groups attendance values **in the chronological order**. A group is something which groups similar attendance values together up until a new attendance value is seen. So the expected output is:

```
eno|date|attendance|attendanceGroup
1|01-Jan-2010|P|1
1|02-Jan-2010|P|1
1|03-Jan-2010|A|2
1|04-Jan-2010|P|3
1|05-Jan-2010|P|3
2|01-Jan-2010|P|1
2|02-Jan-2010|P|1
2|03-Jan-2010|P|1
2|04-Jan-2010|A|2
2|05-Jan-2010|P|3
```

All I could do until now is to get the previous row's attendance value but completely lost on how to go from here...thanks a lot in advance..

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
EmployeeAttendance = Row("eno", "date", "attendance")
EmpAttRowList = [EmployeeAttendance("1", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=100), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("1", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=99), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("1", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=98), "N"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("1", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=97), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("1", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=96), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("1", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=95), "N"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("1", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=94), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("1", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=93), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=100), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=99), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=98), "N"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=97), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=96), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=95), "N"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=94), "N"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=93), "N"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=92), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=91), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("2", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=90), "N"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("3", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=97), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("3", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=96), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("3", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=95), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("3", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=94), "N"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("3", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=93), "N"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("3", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=92), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("3", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=91), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("3", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=90), "Y"),
                 EmployeeAttendance("3", datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=89), "Y")
                ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(EmpAttRowList, EmployeeAttendance)
window = Window.partitionBy(df['eno']).orderBy("date")
previousrowattendance = lag(df["attendance"]).over(window)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have the dataframe created already using above mentioned code, you can use the below code to get the *attendanceGroup*. Let me know if it works.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

winSpec = Window.partitionBy('eno').orderBy('date')
df_unique = df.withColumn('prevAttendance', F.lag('attendance').over(winSpec))
df_unique = df_unique.filter((df_unique.attendance != df_unique.prevAttendance) | F.col('prevAttendance').isNull())
df_unique = df_unique.withColumn('attendanceGroup', F.row_number().over(winSpec))
df_unique = df_unique.withColumnRenamed('eno', 'eno_t').withColumnRenamed('date', 'date_t').drop('attendance').drop('prevAttendance')
df = df.join(df_unique, (df.eno == df_unique.eno_t) & (df.date == df_unique.date_t), 'left').drop('eno_t').drop('date_t')
df = df.withColumn('attendanceGroup', F.last('attendanceGroup', ignorenulls = True).over(winSpec))
df.orderBy('eno', 'date').show(10, False)

+---+----------+----------+---------------+
|eno|date      |attendance|attendanceGroup|
+---+----------+----------+---------------+
|1  |2019-08-16|Y         |1              |
|1  |2019-08-17|Y         |1              |
|1  |2019-08-18|N         |2              |
|1  |2019-08-19|Y         |3              |
|1  |2019-08-20|Y         |3              |
|1  |2019-08-21|N         |4              |
|1  |2019-08-22|Y         |5              |
|1  |2019-08-23|Y         |5              |
|2  |2019-08-16|Y         |1              |
|2  |2019-08-17|Y         |1              |
+---+----------+----------+---------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

Comment: big thanks for your help..this ```df = df.withColumn('attendanceGroup', F.last('attendanceGroup', ignorenulls = True).over(winSpec))``` is pretty sweet..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Create a `grp` flag with condition `attendance != lag(attendance)` to facilitate summing over the flag
2. Create a new Window partitioned by the original id `eno` and newly created `grp` flag column, and apply a `sum`, and *add 1 basically for starting the counter from 1*.

```
window = Window.partitionBy("eno").orderBy("date")

df = df.withColumn('grp', F.when(F.col("attendance") != F.lag(F.col("attendance")).over(window), 1).otherwise(0))
df = df.withColumn("group", 1 + F.sum(F.col("grp")).over(Window.partitionBy("eno", "grp").orderBy("date"))).drop("grp").orderBy("eno", "date")
```

**Output**

```
+---+----------+----------+-----+
|eno|      date|attendance|group|
+---+----------+----------+-----+
|  1|2019-08-17|         Y|    1|
|  1|2019-08-18|         Y|    1|
|  1|2019-08-19|         N|    2|
|  1|2019-08-20|         Y|    3|
|  1|2019-08-21|         Y|    1|
|  1|2019-08-22|         N|    4|
|  1|2019-08-23|         Y|    5|
|  1|2019-08-24|         Y|    1|
|  2|2019-08-17|         Y|    1|
|  2|2019-08-18|         Y|    1|
|  2|2019-08-19|         N|    2|
|  2|2019-08-20|         Y|    3|
|  2|2019-08-21|         Y|    1|
|  2|2019-08-22|         N|    4|
|  2|2019-08-23|         N|    1|
|  2|2019-08-24|         N|    1|
|  2|2019-08-25|         Y|    5|
|  2|2019-08-26|         Y|    1|
|  2|2019-08-27|         N|    6|
|  3|2019-08-20|         Y|    1|
+---+----------+----------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: I think above solution needs to be improved. The record:  (1#2019-08-21#Y)    should have group number as 3 instead of 1 marked in answer.